# Android add event using event id with manual view in Calendar

Tags: android

I want to add event manually

```
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(Events._ID, 1)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "MyEventOn")
            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            .putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
            startActivityForResult(intent);

no value in 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //resultCode always returns 0.
    switch(requestCode) {
    case 1: 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Whether I click "Save" or "Cancel" in the calendar app, the resultCode always gives 0.

additionally I need to get the data back from the calendar intent.But The intent "data" in the onActivityResult also returns null.

Could anyone explain why it happens? Is there any way to know if user clicks "Save" or "Cancel"?

any other solution for this but want to add event using default page of calender with my event id.

If Any Solution Please Give Me Solution.

Answer (score 0):

In you want to receive a result for a particular `Intent`, use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` instead of `startActivity`. The requestCode should be something unique, and it should also be the requestCode that you are switching on in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: yes i am changing startActivity to startActivityForResult but same issue. Please give any solution